# Laravel package development - How to install Illuminate Foundation without requiring laravel/framework?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-10

I'm currently developing a Laravel package. The service provider of this package relies on magic methods `config('my.config')` and `config_path('../my-config.php')` defined in [Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php](https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L252). PHPStorm notifies that it can't find these magic methods.

- How to make sure that these dependencies resolve?
- Is it possible to check which package installed a certain namespace in Composer?

Things I tried:

- The standalone package: https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/foundation This package is apparently abandoned. No alternatives provided
- Install the entire laravel/framework. This conflicts with the application with which I try to install the package. I also want to avoid installing unnecessary dependencies in the package.
- I tried a bunch of packages from Illuminate: config, container and contracts. When I check the vendor folder, I don't see any foundation directory in the Illuminate directory

Comment: And if the laravel framework is only a dev dependency, then use it only as a dev dependency.

Comment: @hakre When I require laravel/framework, it is there so somehow that namespace is added with one of the other Illuminate packages.

Comment: @hakre Listening it as a dev dependency is a good idea. Will look into it

Comment: Yes, that certainly could be. When installing a dependency with Composer it is normally that code with namespaces is added.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've required it as a dev dependency which of course works.

Answer (score 1):

I have required the Laravel framework as a dev dependency instead.